# SQLAlchemy/Pyramid tutorial: attempt to write to readonly database

Tags: sqlalchemy, runtime-error, pyramid, readonly

I am banging my head over this one. I have successfully completed the SQLAlcemy + URL Dispatch tutorial in the past. Now whatever I do, the attempts to write to the sqlite db file all fail, throwing:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database u'INSERT INTO pages (name, data) VALUES (?, ?)' (u'NewPage', u'A new page is dawning.')
```

The variations in my current configuration are:

- I am running through the tutorial under mod_wsgi, not the pserve.
- result is the same running under pserve
- this system is running python 2.6.5 vs 2.7.5

The datafile initializes fine. The ownership is the same as the wsgi process owner. I'm baffled.

Here's the models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Index,
    Integer,
    Text,
    )

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()


class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    data = Column(Text)

    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data

Index('page_index', Page.name, unique=True, mysql_length=255)
```

Pretty straightforward out of the tutorial.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere around filesystem permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daemon process owner could not write to the file even though the same owner created the file. WTF?   Anyway, manually setting 666 on the sqlite file has cleared this up.

Comment: ... which is a sign that the effective user of your wsgi process is different from what you think it is :)